# How to access AWS Glue Job Apply Mapping Metadata to create a source to target report

Tags: metadata, aws-glue

I have crawlers to access my external data sources and store metadata.  I have mapped the source to target columns, name changes and data type transformations in an apply mapping step in my Glue jobs.  What I want to do is access this mapping meta data as part of a comprehensive source to target mapping report.   Not evident how to accomplish this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Researched where AWS Glue Job meta data was stored without success.